# Encoding data in utf-8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

For a project I have to download data of many cities in the world, so with several special characters or accent, but I can't visualize it well.

I have tried to encode it with utf-8 but without luck: I do know why but I haven't errors from terminal but I continue to visualize city name like this one: `L'H\u00f4pital Puits II`, or this other one `Marsza\u0142kowska, Warszawa`.

Can someone help pinpoint the error, or what can I try?

```
import requests

w = open("cittadine.txt","wb")

fullMap = requests.get("http://aqicn.org/map/world/").text
print type(fullMap) # <type 'unicode'>
fullMap = fullMap.encode("utf-8")
w.writelines(fullMap)
```

Comment: I posted simlar question 30 minutes ago. Maybe your command line is not set to utf-8. Try this command: chcp 65001

Comment: @DatamineR thanks for your answers but I don't resolve with your tip. And I continue to visualize errors in txt format file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok. The reason you're getting `{L'H\u00f4pital Puits II}}`, is because the server is sending that exact string!

```
curl "http://aqicn.org/map/world/" | grep -o "L'H\\\\u00f4pital Puits II"
L'H\u00f4pital Puits II
```

That string appears in a block of JSON, so you need to find that block, then use the JSON module to decode it, which should convert this Unicode point back to a proper character.

Beautiful Soup is probably the best way to find the JSON block.

**Suggestion**

A neater way to write UTF-8 to a file is to use an encoding TextWrapper, which will automatically encode Unicode chars on write:

```
import requests
import io

w = io.open("cittadine.txt","w", encoding="utf-8")

fullMap = requests.get("http://aqicn.org/map/world/").text
print type(fullMap) # <type 'unicode'>
w.write(fullmap)
```

If you need to write Unicode to a Windows terminal, install https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console

Comment: Thanks, I will try with beatifulsoup